# What is the process for getting a dev-kit for Xbox 360 to allow native coding

Tags: xbox360

I'm curious about the process of getting a Xbox 360 dev-kit.

What are the requirements? Do you have to have a track record in game development. Can indie gamers get one. How much does it cost? Is there special hardware?

Comment: its now 2015 and things have moved on a bit. Self publishing is the way forward, simply apply to ID@xbox program and see what happens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, [RTFM](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/developers/faq#developer).

So either you work for a *certified Xbox 360 publisher*, and/or you're already in contact with a *Developer Account Manager*, but that would mean that you're already an established developer so you wouldn't be asking this question.

Or you request to join the *Registered Developers Program* that allows indies to access devkits and the XDK. This is done simply via email. This seems to be less restrictive, but you'll still have to prove that you can make proper games (e.g. you have "personnel with significant previous professional game development industry experience"), sign an NDA, and probably purchase a devkit.

Comment: TFM doesn't have anything about costs or specific company requirements

Comment: For this you'll have to talk directly to Microsoft, and this discussion will be under NDA. You won't find more information that's publicly available.

Comment: I was hoping that there might be some nda-leaks out there

Answer (score 0):

You need to have money and you need to have a publisher with several published AAA titles.

It is indeed a special piece of hardware - nowadays not so much because of the actual hardware (which is slightly different), but because it gives you more freedom when running games (dev mode, debugging, etc.)

It's pretty pointless for indies anyway. However if you only want to experiment with native 360 stuff and not release a game, I believe there are some legally gray areas that allow you to do that.